# Icron Upload directory watcher issue

Tags: php, incron

I'm using CentOS on a VPS, I have installed Incron to watch a folder for file uploads, this is the `incrontab -e` command I'm using :

```
/home/user/public_html/uploads IN_CLOSE_WRITE /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/uploads/watcher.php $#

//The $@ sends the file name as montioned in the Icron tutorial here :
```

[Incron tuto 1](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/)
[Incron tuto 2](http://www.epicserve.com/blog/2011/dec/13/using-incron-monitor-newly-uploaded-files/)

this is the content of watcher.php

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("text.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $argv[1]."\n");//Argument 1 is the name of the file, argv[0] is the script name.
fclose($myfile);
```

when I upload one file "myphpfile.php" Icron works and saved the name in the "text.txt" file however when I open it I found so many lines with the name of the file uploaded :

```
text.txt :
myphpfile.php
myphpfile.php
myphpfile.php
myphpfile.php
myphpfile.php
.....
```

I'm uploading only one file, the "text.txt" file should have only one line, I know I could open the file using "w" but this will only delete all entries and save the last one. I mean using appened "a" shows that something is wrong with Incron when uploading files using `"IN_CLOSE_WRITE"` as watch event.
I can't find any event to handle upload files.  Can you help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Find a sulution my self. For those how may be interested : just had to add IN_NO_LOOP after "IN_CLOSE_WRITE"  like this : /home/user/public_html/uploads IN_CLOSE_WRITE, IN_NO_LOOP /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/uploads/watcher.php $#